# Subtract 2 pyspark dataframes based on column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have 2 pyspark dataframes,

```
i
+---+-----+
| ID|COL_A|
+---+-----+
|  1|  123|
|  2|  456|
|  3|  111|
|  4|  678|
+---+-----+
j
+----+-----+
|ID_B|COL_B|
+----+-----+
|   2|  456|
|   3|  111|
|   4|  876|
+----+-----+
```

**I'm trying to subtract `i` from `j` based on values of a particular column i.e., values present in `COL_A` of `i` should not be present in `COL_B` of `j`.**

Expected output should be,

```
diff
+---+-----+
| ID|COL_A|
+---+-----+
|  1|  123|
|  4|  678|
+---+-----+
```

This is my code,

```
common = i.join(j.withColumnRenamed('COL_B', 'COL_A'), ['COL_A'], 'leftsemi')
diff = i.subtract(common)
diff.show()
```

But the output is coming wrong,

```
diff
+---+-----+
| ID|COL_A|
+---+-----+
|  2|  456|
|  1|  123|
|  4|  678|
|  3|  111|
+---+-----+
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
left_join = i.join(j, j.COL_B == i.COL_A,how='left')
left_join.filter(left_join.COL_A.isNull()).show()
```

If you are having column names as args, you can do like:

```
left_join = i.join(j, j[colb] == i[cola],how='left')
left_join.filter(left_join[cola].isNull()).show()
```